# How to align the form elements in all browser

Tags: html

its a simple think,  just i create one registration form, if view the web page in mozila it look fine, if i view the same in internetexplorer it change the text box size how to solve this issue

Comment: if you posted some code we might just be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

You have to style the elements 100% in css. Set the width and height, margin and padding in pixels. If there is any value that is not set, the browsers will parse it diffirent, especially IE.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a table tag, it will do automatic alignment for you.
See example https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp